# Which Python object comparison methods to redefine to make sorted() work?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, redefinition

I feel this question must have been asked before but I could not find an answer.

Suppose I want to implement a Python class whose objects are sortable with `sorted()`. Do I have to reimplement all methods like `__lt__()`, `__gt__()`, etc.? What is the bare minimum? In other words, which method(s) does `sorted()` call for sorting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> **sort**(**, key=None, reverse=False*)
> This method sorts the list in place, using only < comparisons between items. Exceptions are not suppressed - if any comparison operations fail, the entire sort operation will fail (and the list will likely be left in a partially modified state).

So you only need to define `def __lt__(self,other):` for your class.

Also see the [Sorting HOW-TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends) which says near the bottom:

> The sort routines are guaranteed to use `__lt__()` when making comparisons between two objects. So, it is easy to add a standard sort order to a class by defining an `__lt__()` method:

Comment: But is `sorted()` implemented via `sort()`?

Comment: @DYZ The Python sort routines all use `__lt__()`.  See edit for reference.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `functools` built-in method **`total_ordering`** that can decorate your class and enable its instances to be passed to sorted() without a key function specification.

The only requirements for the class is to define any of the comparison dunder methods and `__eq__`.

E.g.:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Sortable:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.x, self.y
    
    def __lt__(self, obj):
        return self.y < obj.y

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        return self.y == obj.y

obj_1 = Sortable("Hello", 9)
obj_2 = Sortable("World", -2)
obj_3 = Sortable("!", 5.5)
print(sorted([obj_1, obj_2, obj_3])
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> [("World", -2), ("!", 5.5), ("Hello", 9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Only `__lt__` is required. See the following example:

```
class MyCustomNumber:
    def __init__(self, some_number):
        self.some_number = some_number

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.some_number < other.some_number
    
list_ = [MyCustomNumber(1), MyCustomNumber(5), MyCustomNumber(-3), MyCustomNumber(150)]

for x in sorted(list_):
    print(x.some_number)
```

Outputs:

```
-3
1
5
150
```

Even `sorted(list_, reverse=True)` works with just `__lt__` implemented.